# How to Convert Two Lists into String Format Flutter

Tags: string, list, flutter, dart

Two Lists With User Input

```
List1 = [0,1,2,3,...];
List2 = [0.1,0.2,0.3,...];
```

Note: Length of Both Lists is from User Input

I want to Represent Data Like this As a String

```
var Result = "0 * 0.1 + 1 *0.2 + 3 * 0.3 ,......";
print(result);
```

Comment: what is the problem ? what have you tried ? A simple loop, string extrapolation and that's it ..

Comment: can you please code a loop

Comment: `final list1 = [0,1,2];
final list2 = [0.1,0.2,0.3];
final zipped = IterableZip([list1, list2]);
final result = zipped.map((z) => '${z[0]} * ${z[1]}').join(' + ');
print(result);`

Comment: @pskink Bro Length is not fixed

Comment: i dont use any fixed length: both lists can have 3 or 33 or 3333 items, for example: `final list1 = [0,1,2,3,4,5]; final list2 = [0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this result like your example

```dart
    final l1 = [0, 1, 2];
    final l2 = [0.1, 0.2, 0.3];
    
    String result = '';
    for (int i = 0; i < l1.length; i++) {
      final l1Value = l1[i];
      final l2Value = l2[i];
      if (l1Value == null || l2Value == null) {
        break;
      }
      final multiple = '$l1Value * $l2Value';
      result = '$result ${result.isEmpty ? '': '+'} $multiple';
    }
```

Comment: it still gives two extra spaces at the beginning, whats wrong with `Iterable.join`? simple `iterable.join(' + ')` makes a trick

Answer (score 1):

You can use List.join() to achieve your result

```
  List List1 = [0,1,2,3];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SizedBox(
        height: 400, child: Text(List1.join(",")));
  }
```

result - 0,1,2,3

```
    List List1 = [0, 1, 2, 3];
    List List2 = ["a", "b", "c", "D"];
    List mixList = [];
    for (int i = 0; i < List1.length; i++) {
      mixList.add("${List1[i]}*${List2[i]}");
      print(mixList);
    }
    return Text(mixList.join(","));
```

Comment: Bro this is for one List

Comment: i want to Merge both list like this "0 * 0.1 + 1 *0.2 + 3 * 0.3"

Comment: List1 [0] * List2[0] +  List1 [1] * List2[1] + List1 [2] * List2[2] + List1 [3] * List2[3]